# Windows defender reports trojan Win64/Longage in 2 Ubuntu files

Tags: security, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, antivirus, trojan

I am using Ubuntu on Windows 10, and my windows defender just reported trojan in two Ubuntu files:

- `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0.0`
- `/usr/lib/apt/methods/http`

Are these files safe to use (unblock in Windows Defender)?

---

This is specifically what it shows:

[image: "Threat quarantined" report for "libapt-private.so.0.0.0"]

[image: "Threat quarantined" report for "http"]

Comment: Yep, I've had the same experience today.  Unfortunately, requesting Windows Defender to unblock doesn't appear to have been successful.  So I'm now stuck with a WSL installation that's non-upgradeable currently.